# How to read Wiegand card ID?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, wiringpi, pigpio

I need a simple script that outputs ID of presented card in console. I tried a lot of opensource code that based on WiringPi library, e.g. [Pidoorman](http://tonigor.com/pidoorman/wiegand.c), its forks by Kyle Mallory and E.J. Dyksen, RFID Access Control System by Laserbird from Instructables etc. but no one works correctly.

I'm sure that I connected all right cause [that script](https://gist.github.com/hsiboy/9598741#file-wiegand-c) (fork of Pidoorman wiegand.c by Kyle Mallory) changed its output when card presented:

```
Read 14 bits (2 bytes): DF31 : 1101111100110001
Read 15 bits (2 bytes): F701 : 1111011100000001
Read 18 bits (3 bytes): DFC001 : 110111111100000000000001
Read 19 bits (3 bytes): EFF001 : 111011111111000000000001
Read 17 bits (3 bytes): DFC300 : 110111111100001100000000
Read 76 bits (10 bytes): 9BBFC4EBDD57BA7E7C0D : 10011011101111111100010011101011110111010101011110111010011111100111110000001101
Read 30 bits (4 bytes): EEFF802E : 11101110111111111000000000101110
Read 14 bits (2 bytes): DF01 : 1101111100000001
Read 15 bits (2 bytes): EF66 : 1110111101100110
Read 15 bits (2 bytes): EF61 : 1110111101100001
Read 14 bits (2 bytes): DF21 : 1101111100100001
```

But I need something more human-readible and without constant (and wrong) output of pin state.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can reliably read Wiegand devices with my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

There is C, C++, and Python example code at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html

Comment: Hi Joan, thank you for your suggestion. Could you please briefly describe principles how your software works? I compile and run your **test_wiegand.c** and I saw constantly repeated messages, something like: `bits=33 value=2871350613` `bits=35 value=2773790381` `bits=49 value=1420481877` etc. It's similar like wiegand.c by Kyle Mallory based on WiringPi library. But I need to output card ID only when it's presented, when contoroller receive interrupt. Or you think that I have some problems with hardware, like unstable voltage or contact chatter?

Comment: The software is normally in an idle state.  When activity (falling edge) is detected on the green wire (0) or the white wire (1) the bits are accumulated.  When there is no activity on the green or white wire for (a default) 5 ms the code is considered complete and its value and length are printed.  The software is then back in the idle state.  You appear to be picking up random noise.  Have you connected the ground wire?  Is something loose?  Can you post a close-up photo of your set-up?

Comment: Here is my schematics http://i.imgur.com/9EMJQQs.png and photo http://i.imgur.com/ixk29XO.jpg

Comment: I don't understand the point of the diodes.  I've not noticed them in other Wiegand wiring diagrams.  Mind you I've only looked at a couple of wiring diagrams.  However there does not seem to be a ground between the Wiegand and the Pi.  I'd expect a ground wire to come from the Wiegand like the green/white wires and for that ground wire to be connected to the Pi ground.

Comment: I also don't understand completely for what diode is needed (I assume for stabilizing voltage and current), but some DIY projects like [Pidoorman](http://tonigor.com/pidoorman/) use them. Will try to make a common ground wire between Wiegand and Raspberry tomorrow and tell about result.

Comment: The real problem is there is no ground connection between the Wiegand unit and the Pi.  A ground connection is needed to complete the circuit for the green and white wires.

Comment: One of the wires coming out of the thick grey cable must be ground, presumably you are powering the device using that black connector by connecting ground and a +ve voltage. Can't you split that ground off to the Pi as well?

Comment: Hi Joan, sorry for delay in reply. With common ground betwwen Pi and reader everything work fine, thanks :)

Comment: You need those diodes because Wiegand readers are 5V signals and Raspberry GPIO are 3.3V. With those diodes you downshift voltage without burning your RPi.

Answer (score 1):

Check also my C interrupt-driven implementation, using wiringpi at https://bitbucket.org/sivann/wiegand_rpi/src

Check the wiegand_rpi.c simple reader